# Lottie animation return this Error: Lottie doesn't support 3D layers

Tags: java, android, lottie

Every time I run my app, this error is given: Error: Lottie doesn't support 3D layers.
In the same app there are more LottieAnimationView and no error is given, only this one return it.
LottieAnimationView declare like this:

```
LottieAnimationView bookAnimation = findViewById(R.id.backToSchoolAnimation);
bookAnimation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

layout declare like this:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                android:id="@+id/backToSchoolAnimation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="450dp"
                app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/back_to_school" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: well perhaps it's just the lottie file you have which isn't valid

Comment: i have tried a lot of files, this is the link: https://lottiefiles.com/30305-back-to-school